# Mutual auth - AsyncRestTemplate support

Tags: java, spring

I use AsyncRestTemplate in spring for passing data to a third party  server. 
I need to pass client certificate as mutual auth is enabled. 
Any ideas how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this using the PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager ,HttpAsyncClientBuilder